# conditionally validate fields of a class

Tags: python

I have a class with fields like so

Class

- request code enum
- name
- address
- phone

What I'd like to do is create a validator that validates the fields based on the request code.

For example

Request code == N
validate name is not null
other fields can be null

Request code == NAP
validate name, address, and fields

Is there anyway I can define a list of fields to validate per enum so my validator only checks for those fields? How would I achieve this in python?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It strongly depends on your validator implementation, but in general - yes, you can store a list of fields to validate. There are so many ways to achieve this, for example:

```
fields = {
'N': ['name'],
'NAP': ['name', 'address', 'phone']
}
```

And then get respective fields inside a validator:

```
for field in fields['NAP']:
    value = getattr(your_object, field) 
    # validation logic ...
```

But note that there are a lot of more flexible ways to validate the object

Comment: ahh thanks `getattr()` function is the key part that i was missing!